# Maintain develop and production npm packages using different git branches

Tags: npm-install

We have code with a number of shared modules.

Ideally, we would like to have each module be it's own package.

But, we also need to work from production, testing, and development code branches.

Is there anyway easy way to use the npm mechanism to support this.

I know we could do something with aliases, and links, but we're wondering if there is a different way.